# Problema con plugin FullCalendar JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, aplicación-web, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema con el funcionamiento del plugin de js "fullcalendar".

Me funciona todo bien: el añadir eventos, editarlos, eliminarlos, mostrarlos en el calendario con las horas correctas... Pero a la hora de navegar por los meses con las flechas "prev" y "next" no funciona correctamente.

Cuando voy hacia adelante o hacia atrás se cambian los meses correctamente pero el nombre del no corresponde con el mes mostrado, va con retraso. Es decir, si estamos en Enero y doy una vez a la flecha de "Next", se cambia al mes de Febrero pero en el texto superior sigue apareciendo Enero, después si pulso la flecha de "Prev", cambia al mes de Enero de nuevo y el texto es cuando cambia a Febrero.

Es algo bastante extraño y no encuento la forma de solucionarlo.

Adjunto el código de la conf. inicial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Initialize FullCalendar */
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#example-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            language: 'es',
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: 'load.php',
        timeFormat: "HH:mm",
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        displayEventTime: true,
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view){
            element.css("background-color", "#DF0101");
        },
        // Función para crear un nuevo evento en el calendario al seleccionar días
        select: function(start, end, allDay){
            $("#modalAnyadir").modal("show");
        },
        // Función para editar el evento al hacer doble click encima de él
        eventRender: function(event, element){
            element.bind("dblclick", function(){
                $("#modalEditar").modal("show");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Y no veo ninguna forma de corregir esto. Si hace falta que muestre cualquier otro código me avisan.

***EDITADO***
Por ejemplo, se carga el calendario, y en la imagen que adjunto, donde aparece "enero 2019", al cargar el calendario aparece ese texto en blanco, sin nada. Entonces pulso la flecha de "Next" (marcada con un círculo rojo en la imagen), aparece el mes de febrero (como se puede observar en los días) pero en el texto superior aparece "enero 2019". Y al cargar el calendario tampoco aparecen los eventos de enero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Copié el html que compartiste y ejecuté el calendario, la verdad no logro ver cuál es el error que tienes. ¿Podrías adjuntar imágenes?

Comment: He adjuntado una imagen @ValVert

Comment: A mi no me sucede el error, favor añade las referencias que estás utilizando (jquery, fullcalendar etc) y sus versiones.

Comment: Añadiré lo que tengo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo conversado el problema se podría encontrar en tus referencias y/o versiones, adjunto mi código y réplica mediante una imagen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>recTime | v2.0</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
  <script src='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <script src='javascript/fullcalendar-3.9.0/locale/es.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      /* Initialize FullCalendar */
      var date = new Date();
      var d = date.getDate();
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var y = date.getFullYear();

      $('#example-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                language: 'es',
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            //events: 'load.php',
            timeFormat: "HH:mm",
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            displayEventTime: true,
            eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view){
                element.css("background-color", "#DF0101");
            },
            // Función para crear un nuevo evento en el calendario al seleccionar días
            select: function(start, end, allDay){
                $("#modalAnyadir").modal("show");
            },
            // Función para editar el evento al hacer doble click encima de él
            eventRender: function(event, element){
                element.bind("dblclick", function(){
                    $("#modalEditar").modal("show");
                });
            }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='example-fullcalendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Imagen de solución, esto sucede al cargar el calendario, osea, se muestra el título del mes y al cambiar con los botones de *prev*,*next* no tengo problemas en la navegación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]